# if block not executing when adding multiple conditions

Tags: java

I am running this program to find even numbers in the array, but i do not want my program to check the index 1 of the array. So I did this,

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14 };

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if ((i != 1)){
            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

it gives the correct output,

```
4 6 8 10 12 14
```

but if  i add other condition to skip both index `1` and `3`,

i.e,    `if ((i != 1) || (i != 3) )` then `if` block is not executed and i get the following output,

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14
```

instead of, `6 8 10 12 14`

Why the `if` block is not executing the multiple conditions ?

Comment: `((i != 1) && (i != 3) )`

Comment: Read up on de Morgan's laws to learn how to deal with complex conditions. For instance, this may come easier to you: `! (i == 1|| i==3)` and it's the same condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((i != 1) || (i != 3) )
```

This is always true.

- If `i` is neither 1 nor 3, then both conditions are true.
- If `i` is 1, then the right condition is true.
- If `i` is 3, then the left condition is true.

Perhaps you want

```
if (!(i == 1 || i == 3))
```

which is equivalent to

```
if ((i != 1) && (i != 3))
```

by [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: thank you for educating me about *De Morgan's Law*, I literally never heard about it before. Its nice to learn something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition needs to be `if ((i != 1) && (i != 3) )`

Comment: but only one condition would be true at one time, why check both using `&&` ?

Comment: If you want to skip both `1` *and* `3` then you need to build a boolean expression using `&&`. Note that `if ((i != 1) || (i != 3) )` is true for *any* value.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it is supposed to as the `i` variable is either not equal to 1 or not equal to 3 which is true for all numbers. You mean to write `i != 1 && i != 3`